# Microsoft ACE OLE DB 12.0 is not registered on the local machine - But it is

Tags: excel, vb.net, ms-access, ms-office, oledb

I know this is a common error message, and the fix is usually to install [this download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13255), however, my end user has already done this.

I have 2 end users of this program, other than myself. I've got a 64-bit Windows 10 PC, and the first end user also has a 64-bit Windows 10 PC. This user had the problem of not having Ole DB 12.0 installed, so I sent them that link, and wham bam, thank you ma'am, the issue was solved.

***However*** the second end user is running a 64-bit Windows 7 PC - I sent him exactly the same link, and he's installed it (Or so he says), yet the error is still occurring... Is it not compatible with Windows 7, despite the details under the download saying that it is?

Is there anything else that could be causing this issue?

The program is trying to import from Excel to Access, using the following connection path;

```
If ofd.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    txtFile.Text = ofd.FileName

    fi = New FileInfo(ofd.FileName)
    fileName = ofd.FileName

    excel = fi.FullName

    eCon = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & excel & ";Extended Properties=Excel 10.0;")
    eCon.Open()
```

Comment: Hi David....instead of guessing why you don't access to your problematic end user computer with something like TeamViewer and double check if the connector it's installed?...also once you resolve this issue, it should be great if you build a document with your findings

Comment: @Hackerman build a document? Where, on SO?

Comment: No, I mean for you, or for anyone that haves to maintain the software on the future....btw, it's TeamViewer an available option?

Comment: @Hackerman Oh, I see. I didn't need to in the end, they did have it installed but they were missing the 2007 Access engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that your application is compiled for x86 CPUs and not x64. Consequently your app is looking for the 32 bit version of the driver and not the x64 bit one installed. When you installed the 32 bit one your application worked. I get this all the time.

Comment: Right, okay, wasn't aware of that. Not 100% sure if the version he installed is 32bit, but it has been solved so likely that is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was a strange one.

Despite the user having installed the engine correctly, it still wasn't working. I looked in their `Programs and Features` in `Control Panel`, and the only difference was that they were missing the 2007 version of the `Access Engine`.

Installed it, fixed it. No idea why, but in case this happens to anyone else, it's worth checking!